# How to do prepared statements with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a prepared statement. My code is below. I use PHP and MySQLi. I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in/path/path/

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person(name, $lastname)
VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = $sql->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $lastname);
$name= '?';
$lastname='?';
$stmt->execute();
```

The error message points to this line:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare($sql);
```

What is the issue?

Comment: look at this properly. `INSERT INTO person(name, $lastname)` `$lastname`

Comment: INTO person(name, $lastname) - that dollar-sign is wrong

Comment: You define $sql as a string, that is why you can't use it as an object. You should read a bit more about how to use mysqli and objects in generel

Comment: also you should get an undefined variable for `$name` and `$lastname` as you declared them after and not before

Comment: `$sql` is a string as you overwritten it with the query.

Comment: What exactly are you binding with `bind_param()` here? Why are you assigning to `$name` and `$lastname` after you've used them? Are you really assigning `'?'` or is that just an example of something else? I think you need to work through more examples and read more before coming to SE.

Answer (score 0):

You're stomping your database connection with a string, and then everything goes berserk. Fix that:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO person(name, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $lastname);
$name= '?';
$lastname='?';
$stmt->execute();
```

Here `$db` is your database connection, wherever that's created with `new mysqli(...)`.