# Array is repeating every time it loops

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, loops

Every time one of my arrays loops, it repeats the previous arrays along with the new array.

Note in the screenshot below how under Saratoga Springs it lists both the rooms for Saratoga Springs and Grand Floridian.

If I choose a different set of dates that has more results (more resorts with values), all arrays loop into the next array.

Why is my code not stopping the array after its initial loop? How can I fix this, I am baffled.

The PHP query:

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "checkavail") or die ("no database");

$checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
$occupants = $_POST['occupants'];
$sql= "SELECT
            MIN(staydate) AS checkin, MAX(staydate) AS lastnight,
            MIN(available) AS available, ra.resort AS resortcode,
            ri.resort AS resortname, ri.room AS roomname,
            ri.roomcode AS roomcode, ri.view AS viewname,
            SUM(ra.points*20) AS points, ri.sqfoot AS sqfoot,
            ri.description AS roomdescription, ri.bedding AS bedding,
            ri.amenities AS amenities, ri.sleeps AS sleeps,
            ri.sleep_details AS sleepdetails, ri.layout_img AS layoutimg,
            ri.room_img AS roomimg, ri.roomimg_thumb AS roomimgthumb
        FROM resort_availability AS ra
            JOIN room_info AS ri ON (ra.room = ri.roomcode)
        WHERE staydate >= '$checkin' 
        AND staydate < '$checkout'
        AND sleeps >= '$occupants'
        GROUP BY resortcode, roomcode
        ORDER BY resortname, points";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$newarray = [];
foreach($result as $key => $value){
   $newarray[$value['resortcode']][$key] = $value;
}

print_r(json_encode($newarray));

?>
```

The javascript file:

```
$(function getData() {
  $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    var checkin = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var checkout = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var occupants = document.getElementById("party").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { checkin: checkin, checkout: checkout, occupants: occupants },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        searchresult(response);
        
      }
      });
  });
});


let searchresult = function(response) {
    let output = "";
    for (var key in response) {
        var obj = response[key];
        let container = document.getElementById(key+'results');
        for (var prop in obj) {
            output += "<div id="+prop+"><p>"+obj[prop].roomname+" "+ obj[prop].viewname+"</p></div>"
        }
        $(container).html(output);
    }
};
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="akvjhcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
    <div id="akvjhheader" class="resortheader">
        <p class="resortnametext">Animal Kingdom Villas - Jambo House</p>
        <p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p>
        <div id="akvjhresultcount"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="AKVresults"></div>
</div>

<div id="akvkvcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
    <div id="akvkvheader" class="resortheader">
        <p class="resortnametext">Animal Kingdom Villas - Kidani Village</p>
        <p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p>
    </div>
    <div id="AKV2results"></div>
</div>

<div id="aulcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
    <div id="aulheader" class="resortheader">
        <p class="resortnametext">Aulani</p>
        <p class="locationtext">Kapolei, Hawaii</p>
    </div>
    <div id="AULVresults"></div>
</div>

        <div id="bltcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="bltheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Bay Lake Tower</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="BLTresults"></div></div>

        <div id="bcvcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="bcvheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Beach Club Villas</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="BCVresults"></div></div>

        <div id="bwvcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="bwvheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Boardwalk Villas</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="BWALKresults"></div></div>

        <div id="brcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="brheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Boulder Ridge at Wilderness Lodge</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="VWLresults"></div></div>

        <div id="ccvcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="ccvheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Copper Creek at Wilderness Lodge</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="WCCresults"></div></div>

        <div id="vgccontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="vgcheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Grand Californian</p><p class="locationtext">Disneyland - Anaheim, California</p></div>
        <div id="GCALresults"></div></div>

        <div id="vgfcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="vgfheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Grand Floridian Resort & Spa</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p>
        <div id="vgfrescount"></div></div>
        <div id="VGFresults"></div></div>

        <div id="hhicontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="hhiheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Hilton Head Island Resort</p><p class="locationtext">Hilton Head, South Carolina</p></div>
        <div id="HILTNresults"></div></div>

        <div id="okwcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="okwheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Old Key West Resort</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="CLUBresults"></div></div>

        <div id="polycontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="polyheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Polynesian Villas</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="POLYVresults"></div></div>

        <div id="rivcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="rivheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Riviera Resort</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="RVAresults"></div></div>

        <div id="ssrcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="ssrheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Saratoga Springs Resort & Spa</p><p class="locationtext">Walt Disney World - Orlando, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="SSRresults"></div></div>

        <div id="vbrcontainer" class="resortcontainer">
        <div id="vbrheader" class="resortheader"><p class="resortnametext">Vero Beach Resort</p><p class="locationtext">Vero Beach, Florida</p></div>
        <div id="VEROresults"></div></div>
```

Here is a screenshot of it looping...
[image]

Comment: I don't work for Disney. We are a third party. We are cheaper by default, but I am not sure if I am allowed to share our link here...

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: It will be going through Joomla when it's all said and done. So the database connection will change. But, I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array before start to foreach like:

```
$newarray = [];
foreach($result as $key => $value){
   $newarray[$value['resortcode']][$key] = $value;
}
```

Sidenote: please learn how prepare statment ([How to do prepared statements with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083402/how-to-do-prepared-statements-with-php))

Comment: I have updated this in my question, along with adding it to my site. My response is the same and doesn't fix the looping issue.

Comment: if you `var_dump($newarray)` which is the result?

Comment: [VGF] => Array 1, Array 2, Etc.
[SSR] => Array 1, Array 2, Etc.